# Can't horizontally split a bootstrap row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So I want the following layout:

[image]

Here is an artists mock-up:

[image]

But here is what I ended up with after trying for quite a few days:

[image]

I need help to make the last elements line up right. If I use the wrong components you are free to change them. The site needs to be mobile friendly. I have made a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d12tf166/).

```
.
```

I also seem to have the issue of being unable to scroll vertically on the page if overflow occurs.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I'm not sure what your deal is. Some people don't want their code to be changed other than to have what they made work. If changing the entire structure of your work is required to make it work, but it doesn't serve your own constraints then what good is changing the foundation? I came here for help as I can't make the layout I desire. But at least I made all of the code, made a fiddle and asked for help with it, rather than just to have code given to me. So please do elaborate on what seems to be your problem with my request.

Comment: To make it more clear: **you don't need help to learn CSS. You need CSS**.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu I was never taught in HTML/CSS/JavaScript. What I got is self-taught so coming here to ask for help seems reasonable. I don't understand how that would be an insult to the community where most all questions I have answered myself were beginner questions. The same logic could be applied "If you tried for x minutes you'd totally get it!". So I don't give much for that way of thinking. If you know the answer to the question I'd be forever grateful but if you are just going to waste both yours and my time with pointless ranting, then I'd rather you moved on. No hard feelings :)

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu The community is not so black and white that only experts can ask questions here.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Yeah I tried that, but I can't make the two badges stack up vertically like I want in my mock.up. They just keep sitting on top of each other. I could put in hard-coded margins or values that would push the badges into place, but that's not a very nice solution. It'll start breaking as soon as the window changes shape (like going from a PC to a smartphone). No I don't have any employees. It's a one-man company. It could just be that your rant is unjustified.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Maybe you'd be pleased to know that a friend have helped me out to get closer to the solution I seek :)

Answer (score 1):

In bootstrap 3 seems a simple layout like this (just a suggestion)

```
<div  class='container-fluid'>
  <div  class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'>  .... <(div>
</div> <!-- end container full width -->
<div class='container'><!-- begin container center margin auto -->
   <div class=' col-md-12'><img src='yourlink'></div>
   <div class=' col-md-12' ><h1>Title</h1></div>
   <div class='jumbotron col-md-12' </div>
   <div class='row col-md-12>
       <div class='col-md-6>
           ... content for left lower box
      </div>
      <div class='col-md-6'>
            <div> content for r2ght lower 1 box</div>
            <div> content for right lower 2 box</div>
     </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- end of container --!>
```

with a background image

Comment: thank. you. is just a first suggestion but with boostrap you can easily do what you need

Comment: I've settled for a slightly different solution in the end as the design I went for just wasn't plausible within reason. My skills are not good enough for that.

Comment: You should  only understand well (very well) the bootstrap grid system.. for the design you proposed in question. is not diffcult reallly.  but anyway you  know yourself better the anyone.